# In R , how to parse date format from different time zone. Thanks

Tags: r, timezone, lubridate

There is as dataframe as blow,the i want to change "origin_date" to unified format.
lubrite seems can't solve them all.
Is the any pacakge/formular for this? thanks!

```
data.frame(country=c("AU","CA","DE","ES","FR","IN","IT","JP","MX","NL","SE","SG","UA","UK","US"),
                  origin_date=c("9 May 2021 6:23:11 pm GMT+9","May 9, 2021 9:34:27 a.m. PDT","9 mars 2018 12:55:08 UTC+00:00","9 may. 2021 9:24:37 UTC","9 sept. 2020 23:45:52 UTC+00:00","31-Oct-2020 9:54:59 PM GMT+00:00","9 mar 2021 23:04:19 UTC","2021/05/31 9:28:03 JST","9 may. 2021 9:28:04 GMT-7","9 sep 2020 11:51:44 GMT+00:00","9 feb. 2021 22:17:04 UTC","9 May 2021 9:57:53 pm GMT+9","Sep 9, 2020 8:21:34 PM GMT+00:00","9 Sep 2020 23:58:02 GMT+00:00","Sep 9, 2020 9:59:58 AM PDT"))
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: thanks for your reply. please refer to my answer.